# Configuring VNC Windows to Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, fedora, vnc, vncserver

Not sure if this is obvious or just plain weird but I'm having a few issues with VNC between Windows and Linux on my home network.

I've set up TigerVNC on Fedora 12 and I've got Putty running on a separate Windows box to create an ssh session to forward the VNC port so I can connect to the Linux machine. This works fine and I can connect no problem (using TightVNC on Windows).

However, when I launch terminal it begin's "starting terminal" and then nothing happens, it never launches. The same goes when selecting 'Places > Documents' (or 'Places > Desktop') they never load. Most other apps work fine, I can open the firewall configuration, play around in add/remove software, create a note, or open 'My Computer' by clicking on the desktop icon. However, for some reason certain programs won't launch?

This behaviour is only over the VNC session, if I log into the computer directly it works like normal. Any ideas about what's going on here would be appreciated?

Comment: Are you viewing your desktop or some other virtual window?  Things should just work.

Comment: Try Xming if you already use SSH: http://solaris.reys.net/how-to-x11-forwarding-using-ssh-putty-and-xming/

Comment: Did you try running the client from console? There might be errors loged there. It might also help using TigerVNC also on Windows to ensure feature parity (and mayge eliminate some possible quirks)

Answer (score 0):

Put NX Client on the Windows and FreeNX on the linux box. In that way you will not have to use VNC, and you will get a more responsive remote desktop that can do drive sharing.